# changing angular2/core directory not working

Tags: typescript, angular

when i using:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
```

from *app.component.ts* my app will be ran successfully but compiler throw the **Error:(1, 25) TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'** whereas core file is in **node_modules/angular2/core** directory!

When I change core directory my app doesn't work but the compiler is ok! 
I'm working on [ANGULAR: 5 MIN QUICKSTART](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html)

[Project Folders Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebT3x.png)

my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the content of the tsconfig.json file? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have the error since the TypeScript compiler can't find the `core.d.ts` file. You need to have the following configuration to make it work. Be careful to the `moduleResolution` attribute that must be set to `node`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node", // <----------
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: my configuration file is like this, but still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to use `system.js`'s `map` property in the main `System.config()` function in the `index.html`